# How to use HTML instead of Markdown in Astro blog posts

Tags: tailwind-css, markdown, astrojs

I have a site I built in Astro and Tailwind but instead of using Markdown with the blog, I want to have the blog pages be regular .astro files.

Alternatively, how do I style the blog post pages if I keep them in Markdown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Markdown supports use of HTML syntax, so you should be able to mix syntaxes or even use pure HTML in a `.md` file.

```
---
title: My Markdown Post
---

<p class="special">
This is styled differently via the `special` class
</p>

This is a regular Markdown paragraph.
```

If you're just looking to apply consistent styles to Markdown content, you can do that by adding styles to the container where you render your Markdown file.

```html
<div class="content">
  <Content />
</div>

<style>
.content :global(h1) {
  color: red;
}
</style>
```

Note the use of the `:global()` selector to reach in and style elements that come from the Markdown document.

Comment: This does not answer the original question. For many things, using markdown is not equivalent to use html. Using html gives you full control over the aspect of your page (use CSS, etc.), allows you to use components in React or other framawork (although Astro supports mdx for this), etc.